# How to create list of tuple by distributing the key to every value element inside a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
A = {7: [21, 29, 43], 16: [20, 21, 37, 49], 21: [7, 16, 43], 29: [2, 7], 43: [7, 21], 46: [23, 36]}
```

I want to distribute the key to every element in the value list and create new list of tuples as follows:

```
B = [(7,21), (7,29), (7,43), (16,20),...]
```

How may I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: B = [(k,v) for k,vs in A.items() for v in vs]

Comment: Mark Tolonen, thank you so much!!! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = {7: [21, 29, 43], 16: [20, 21, 37, 49], 21: [7, 16, 43], 29: [2, 7], 43: [7, 21], 46: [23, 36]}

a = []

for key, values in A.items():
    for value in values:
        a.append((key,value))

print (a)
```

Output:

```
[(7, 21), (7, 29), (7, 43), (16, 20), (16, 21), (16, 37), (16, 49), (21, 7), (21, 16), (21, 43), (29, 2), (29, 7), (43, 7), (43, 21), (46, 23), (46, 36)]
```

Or, using list comprehension:

```
a = [(key,value) for key, values in A.items() for value in values]
```